# Disassemble symbols on shared object file

Tags: debugging, gcc, compilation, android-ndk, disassembly

I've a shared object xlib.so file built with Android-NDK  which I need to deliver. I don't want it to be reverse engineered.

I tried to use 'objdump' and created a disassembled version where I can see something like <_ZNSt6__ndk113__vector_func7_some_other_text@plt> which seems like sort of function labels in front of addresses.

Can I get rid of these informations also so once even someone tries to disassemble the .so file he should not see anything except pure assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot strip *all* symbols from a shared library because those in the
the dynamic symbol table are needed for dynamic linking.

You can strip all other symbols with:

```
strip --strip-all ./libfoo.so
```

or:

```
strip --strip-unneeded ./libfoo.so
```

`--strip-all` looks as if it should strip *all* symbols, and does when applied
to files that are not shared libraries, but `strip` understands the pointlessness
of removing the dynamic symbol table from a shared library.